# Ninject with SignalR on Mono (Ubuntu) - doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, mono, ninject, signalr

I'm setting up a rather small ASP.Net MVC 4 web site on Ubuntu with the help of Mono.

I'm using Ninject for the DI (ver. 3.0.1.10, compiled for Mono).

Everything is fine until I try to add SignalR into play.
I've set up a Hub, checked that everything works on Win. But when deployed to the linux machine I've got an error accessing /signalr/hubs :
http://pastebin.com/shWpzWkP

> System.ArgumentNullException Argument cannot be null. Parameter name:
>
> at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.Object,Ninject.Infrastructure.Multimap2[Ninject.Planning.Bindings.IBindingConfiguration,Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache+CacheEntry]].TryGetValue
>   (System.Object key, Ninject.Infrastructure.Multimap`2& value)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.Clear (System.Object scope)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> at
>   Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule+<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_1
>   (IKernel kernel) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Ninject.GlobalKernelRegistration.MapKernels (System.Action`1
>   action) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at
>   Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule.DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest
>   () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule.b__0
>   (System.Object o, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at (wrapper delegate-invoke)
>   :invoke_void_*this*__object_EventArgs
>   (object,System.EventArgs)
>
> at (wrapper delegate-invoke)
>   :invoke_void_*this*__object_EventArgs
>   (object,System.EventArgs)
>
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineDone () [0x00000] in :0

I know this is a complex and unsupported scenario, but is there anything I can do to make it work? Or at least somehow completely disable Ninject for SignalR hubs (because plain site with SignalR works on Mono smoothly).

Comment: and the trickiest thing is - if I aggressively hit F5 at /signalr/hubs in a browser, it correctly displays JavaScript in 1 out of 10 times.